# You Tube 360 video not working

Tags: 14.04, youtube

I'm trying to see 360 You Tube videos but they are not working. I'm using latest version of Chrome, html5 player and I enabled hardvare acceleration but it's still not working. I can see flat version of the video.

What can I do to fix this issue?